# registration form can't redirect using codeigniter

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

I make the login form and the registration in one page, but I have had problems in the registration form that, when my registration is not redirect to the page I wanted, but i have notice "404 The page you are looking for could not be found!", but the data have already been entered into the registration form successfully saved to the database. the data that is included on the registration form that can be used to login!

## Login Controller

```
<?php class Login extends Front {

var $customer;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->customer = \CI::Login()->customer();
}

public function login($redirect= '')
{
    //find out if they're already logged in
    if (\CI::Login()->isLoggedIn(false, false))
    {

        redirect($redirect);
    }

    \CI::load()->library('form_validation');
    \CI::form_validation()->set_rules('email', 'lang:address_email', ['trim','required','valid_email']);
    \CI::form_validation()->set_rules('password', 'Password', ['required', ['check_login_callable', function($str){
        $email = \CI::input()->post('email');
        $password = \CI::input()->post('password');
        $remember = \CI::input()->post('remember');
        $login = \CI::Login()->loginCustomer($email, sha1($password), $remember);
        if(!$login)
        {
            \CI::form_validation()->set_message('check_login_callable', lang('login_failed'));
            return false;
        }
    }]]);

    if (\CI::form_validation()->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->view('login', ['redirect'=>$redirect, 'loginErrors'=>\CI::form_validation()->get_error_array()]);
    }
    else
    {
        redirect($redirect);
    }
}

public function logout()
{
    \CI::Login()->logoutCustomer();
    redirect('login');
}

public function forgotPassword()
{
    $data['page_title'] = lang('forgot_password');

    \CI::form_validation()->set_rules('email', 'lang:address_email', ['trim', 'required', 'valid_email',
        ['email_callable', function($str)
            {
                $reset = \CI::Customers()->reset_password($str);

                if(!$reset)
                {
                    \CI::form_validation()->set_message('email_callable', lang('error_no_account_record'));
                    return FALSE;
                }
                else
                {
                    //user does exist. and the password is reset.
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }
        ]
    ]);

    if (\CI::form_validation()->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->view('forgot_password', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        \CI::session()->set_flashdata('message', lang('message_new_password'));
        redirect('login');
    }
}

public function register()
{
    $redirect  = \CI::Login()->isLoggedIn(false, false);
    //if they are logged in, we send them back to the my_account by default
    if ($redirect)
    {
        redirect('my-account');
    }

    \CI::load()->library('form_validation');

    //default values are empty if the customer is new
    $data = [
        'company' => '',
        'firstname' => '',
        'lastname' => '',
        'email' => '',
        'phone' => '',
        'address1' => '',
        'address2' => '',
        'city' => '',
        'state' => '',
        'zip' => '',

        'redirect' => \CI::session()->flashdata('redirect')
    ];

    \CI::form_validation()->set_rules('company', 'lang:account_company', 'trim|max_length[128]');
    \CI::form_validation()->set_rules('firstname', 'lang:account_firstname', 'trim|required|max_length[32]');
    \CI::form_validation()->set_rules('lastname', 'lang:account_lastname', 'trim|required|max_length[32]');
    \CI::form_validation()->set_rules('email', 'lang:account_email', ['trim','required','valid_email','max_length[128]', ['check_email_callable', function($str){
        return $this->check_email($str);
    }]]);
    \CI::form_validation()->set_rules('phone', 'lang:account_phone', 'trim|required|max_length[32]');
    \CI::form_validation()->set_rules('email_subscribe', 'lang:email_subscribe', 'trim|numeric|max_length[1]');
    \CI::form_validation()->set_rules('password', 'lang:account_password', 'required|min_length[6]');
    \CI::form_validation()->set_rules('confirm', 'lang:account_confirm', 'required|matches[password]');


    if (\CI::form_validation()->run() == FALSE)
    {
        //if they have submitted the form already and it has returned with errors, reset the redirect
        if (\CI::input()->post('submitted'))
        {
            $data['redirect'] = \CI::input()->post('redirect');
        }

        // load other page content 
        //\CI::load()->model('banner_model');
        \CI::load()->helper('directory');

        $data['registrationErrors'] = \CI::form_validation()->get_error_array();

        $this->view('login', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        $save['id'] = false;
        $save['firstname'] = \CI::input()->post('firstname');
        $save['lastname']  = \CI::input()->post('lastname');
        $save['email'] = \CI::input()->post('email');
        $save['phone'] = \CI::input()->post('phone');
        $save['company'] = \CI::input()->post('company');
        $save['active'] = (bool)config_item('new_customer_status');
        $save['email_subscribe'] = intval((bool)\CI::input()->post('email_subscribe'));

        $save['password']  = sha1(\CI::input()->post('password'));

        $redirect  = \CI::input()->post('redirect');

        //if we don't have a value for redirect
        if ($redirect == '')
        {
            $redirect = 'my-account';
        }

        // save the customer info and get their new id
        \CI::Customers()->save($save);

        //send the registration email
        \GoCart\Emails::registration($save);

        //load twig for this language string
        $loader = new \Twig_Loader_String();
        $twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);

        //if they're automatically activated log them in and send them where they need to go
        if($save['active'])
        {
            \CI::session()->set_flashdata('message', $twig->render( lang('registration_thanks'), $save) );

            //lets automatically log them in
            \CI::Login()->loginCustomer($save['email'], $save['password']);

            //to redirect them, if there is no redirect, the it should redirect to the homepage.
            redirect($redirect);
        }
        else
        {
            //redirect to the login page if they need to wait for activation
            \CI::session()->set_flashdata('message', $twig->render( lang('registration_awaiting_activation'), $save) );
            redirect('login');
        }
    }
}

public function check_email($str)
{
    $email = \CI::Customers()->check_email($str);

    if ($email)
    {
        \CI::form_validation()->set_message('check_email_callable', lang('error_email'));
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}}
```

## Login Models

```
<?php Class Login extends CI_Model{

public function __construct()
{
    $customer = CI::session()->userdata('customer');

    if(empty($customer))
    {
        //If we don't have a customer, check for a cookie.
        if(isset($_COOKIE['GoCartCustomer']))
        {
            //the cookie is there, lets log the customer back in.
            $info = $this->aes256Decrypt(base64_decode($_COOKIE['GoCartCustomer']));
            $cred = json_decode($info);

            if(is_object($cred))
            {
                $this->loginCustomer($cred->email, $cred->password, true);
                if( ! $this->isLoggedIn() )
                {
                    // cookie data isn't letting us login.
                    $this->logoutCustomer();
                    $this->createGuest();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //cookie is empty
            $this->logoutCustomer();
            $this->createGuest();
        }
    }
}

public function customer()
{
    return CI::session()->userdata('customer');
}

public function logoutCustomer()
{
    CI::session()->unset_userdata('customer');

    //force expire the cookie
    $this->generateCookie('[]', time()-3600);
}

private function generateCookie($data, $expire)
{
    setcookie('GoCartCustomer', $data, $expire, '/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], config_item('ssl_support'), true);
}

public function loginCustomer($email, $password, $remember=false)
{
    $customer = CI::db()->where('is_guest', 0)->
                    where('email', $email)->
                    where('active', 1)->
                    where('password',  $password)->
                    limit(1)->
                    get('customers')->row();

    if ($customer && !(bool)$customer->is_guest)
    {
        // Set up any group discount
        if($customer->group_id != 0)
        {
            $group = CI::Customers()->get_group($customer->group_id);
            if($group) // group might not exist
            {
                $customer->group = $group;
            }
        }

        if($remember)
        {
            $loginCred = json_encode(array('email'=>$customer->email, 'password'=>$customer->password));
            $loginCred = base64_encode($this->aes256Encrypt($loginCred));
            //remember the user for 6 months
            $this->generateCookie($loginCred, strtotime('+6 months'));
        }

        //combine cart items
        if($this->customer())
        {
            $oldCustomer = $this->customer();
            CI::session()->set_userdata('customer', $customer);
            \GC::combineCart($oldCustomer); // send the logged-in customer data
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public function isLoggedIn($redirect = false, $default_redirect = 'login')
{
    //$redirect allows us to choose where a customer will get redirected to after they login
    //$default_redirect points is to the login page, if you do not want this, you can set it to false and then redirect wherever you wish.

    $customer = CI::session()->userdata('customer');

    if(!$customer)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if($customer->is_guest == 1)
    {
        if($redirect)
        {
            redirect($default_redirect);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

private function createGuest()
{
    //create a temp customer
    $customerID = CI::Customers()->createGuest();
    $customer = CI::db()->where('id', $customerID)->get('customers')->row();
    CI::session()->set_userdata('customer', $customer);
}

private function aes256Encrypt($data)
{
    $key = config_item('encryption_key');
    if(32 !== strlen($key))
    {
        $key = hash('SHA256', $key, true);
    }
    $padding = 16 - (strlen($data) % 16);
    $data .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);
    return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, str_repeat("\0", 16));
}

private function aes256Decrypt($data)
{
    $key = config_item('encryption_key');
    if(32 !== strlen($key))
    {
        $key = hash('SHA256', $key, true);
    }
    $data = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, str_repeat("\0", 16));
    $padding = ord($data[strlen($data) - 1]);
    return substr($data, 0, -$padding);
}}
```

## Redirect Function

```
if ( ! function_exists('redirect')){

function redirect($uri = '', $method = 'auto', $code = NULL)
{
    if ( ! preg_match('#^(\w+:)?//#i', $uri))
    {
        $uri = site_url($uri);
    }

    // IIS environment likely? Use 'refresh' for better compatibility
    if ($method === 'auto' && isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) && strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'Microsoft-IIS') !== FALSE)
    {
        $method = 'refresh';
    }
    elseif ($method !== 'refresh' && (empty($code) OR ! is_numeric($code)))
    {
        if (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'], $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] === 'HTTP/1.1')
        {
            $code = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'GET')
                ? 303   // reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get
                : 307;
        }
        else
        {
            $code = 302;
        }
    }

    switch ($method)
    {
        case 'refresh':
            header('Refresh:0;url='.$uri);
            break;
        default:
            header('Location: '.$uri, TRUE, $code);
            break;
    }
    exit;
}}
```

## bootstrap.php

```
$match = $router->match();

    // call a closure
    if( $match && is_callable( $match['target'] ) ) {
        call_user_func_array( $match['target'], $match['params'] );
    }

    // parse a string and call it
    elseif($match && is_string($match['target']))                           
    {
        $target = explode('#', $match['target']);

        try {
            $class = new $target[0];
            call_user_func_array([$class, $target[1]], $match['params']);

        } catch(Exception $e) {
            var_dump($e);
            throw_404();
        }
    }

    // throw a 404 error
    else
    {
        throw_404();
    }
```

## MyAccount.php

```
<?php class MyAccount extends Front {

var $customer;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    \CI::load()->model(array('Locations'));
    $this->customer = \CI::Login()->customer();
}

public function index($offset=0)
{
    //make sure they're logged in
    \CI::Login()->isLoggedIn('my-account');

    $data['customer'] = (array)\CI::Customers()->get_customer($this->customer->id);
    $data['addresses'] = \CI::Customers()->get_address_list($this->customer->id);
    $data['customer_addresses'] = \CI::Customers()->get_address_list($this->customer->id);

    // load other page content
    //\CI::load()->model('banner_model');
    \CI::load()->helper('directory');
    \CI::load()->helper('date');

    // paginate the orders
    \CI::load()->library('pagination');

    $config['base_url'] = site_url('my_account');
    $config['total_rows'] = \CI::Orders()->countCustomerOrders($this->customer->id);
    $config['per_page'] = '15';

    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo;';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['next_link'] = '&raquo;';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    \CI::pagination()->initialize($config);

    $data['orders_pagination'] = \CI::pagination()->create_links();

    $data['orders'] = \CI::Orders()->getCustomerOrders($this->customer->id, $offset);
    //print_r($offset);

    \CI::load()->library('form_validation');
    \CI::form_validation()->set_rules('company', 'lang:address_company', 'trim|max_length[128]');
    \CI::form_validation()->set_rules('firstname', 'lang:address_firstname', 'trim|required|max_length[32]');
    \CI::form_validation()->set_rules('lastname', 'lang:address_lastname', 'trim|required|max_length[32]');
    \CI::form_validation()->set_rules('email', 'lang:address_email', ['trim','required','valid_email','max_length[128]', ['check_email_callable', function($str){
        return $this->check_email($str);
    }]]);
    \CI::form_validation()->set_rules('phone', 'lang:address_phone', 'trim|required|max_length[32]');
    \CI::form_validation()->set_rules('email_subscribe', 'lang:account_newsletter_subscribe', 'trim|numeric|max_length[1]');

    if(\CI::input()->post('password') != '' || \CI::input()->post('confirm') != '')
    {
        \CI::form_validation()->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[6]|sha1');
        \CI::form_validation()->set_rules('confirm', 'Confirm Password', 'required|matches[password]');
    }
    else
    {
        \CI::form_validation()->set_rules('password', 'Password');
        \CI::form_validation()->set_rules('confirm', 'Confirm Password');
    }


    if (\CI::form_validation()->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->view('my_account', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        $customer = [];
        $customer['id'] = $this->customer->id;
        $customer['company'] = \CI::input()->post('company');
        $customer['firstname'] = \CI::input()->post('firstname');
        $customer['lastname'] = \CI::input()->post('lastname');
        $customer['email'] = \CI::input()->post('email');
        $customer['phone'] = \CI::input()->post('phone');
        $customer['email_subscribe'] = intval((bool)\CI::input()->post('email_subscribe'));
        if(\CI::input()->post('password') != '')
        {
            $customer['password'] = \CI::input()->post('password');
        }

        \GC::save_customer($this->customer);
        \CI::Customers()->save($customer);

        \CI::session()->set_flashdata('message', lang('message_account_updated'));

        redirect('my-account');
    }

}

public function check_email($str)
{
    if(!empty($this->customer->id))
    {
        $email = \CI::Customers()->check_email($str, $this->customer->id);
    }
    else
    {
        $email = \CI::Customers()->check_email($str);
    }

    if ($email)
    {
        \CI::form_validation()->set_message('check_email_callable', lang('error_email'));
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}

public function download($link)
{
    $filedata = \CI::DigitalProducts()->get_file_info_by_link($link);

    // missing file (bad link)
    if(!$filedata)
    {
        show_404();
    }

    // validate download counter
    if($filedata->max_downloads > 0)
    {
        if(intval($filedata->downloads) >= intval($filedata->max_downloads))
        {
            show_404();
        }
    }

    // increment downloads counter
    \CI::DigitalProducts()->touch_download($link);

    // Deliver file
    \CI::load()->helper('download');
    force_download('uploads/digital_uploads/', $filedata->filename);
}}
```

Comment: First of all chk debug `$redirect` what r u getting in this, second u r using site_url() did u load uri library?

Comment: What version of codeigniter is this?

Comment: in bootstrap.php not go to try but to catch var_dam ($ e), everything is normal except register! but data on the contents of the form to go into the database!

Comment: I do not know how many versions of this CodeIgniter, but this CodeIgniter 2015